# How do I remove the shadows on the top and bottom of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using UIVisualEffectsView (With Vibrancy) through the IB. I cant seem to get rid of these shadows.

### **Update: Those aren't shadows. When a part of the cell becomes invisble, the invisible part is blurred (hence, black) and not the previous content**

[image: image 2]

---

- I have no code related to shadows
- I have disabled tableview bounce
- I have tried to set the layer shadowOpacity to 0 in all tableviewcell subviews

Please tell me if I need to provide more information to clarify my doubt.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: please check your header and footer height in Xib or Storyboard .

Comment: tableview.tableHeader?

Comment: Yes . And If those are not header and footer of table, then check the tabbar .I guess the lower shadow is tabBar .

Comment: I set the shadows of the tableheader/footer to 0; Still the same. Also, its not the tabbar/ nav bar because the same shadows exist even if the table view is far from them

Comment: set background colour for each object so that you will able to know that the gap is in which view ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I moved my tableview under the navigation bar and tab bar and then set them to translucent. Now the shadow(like) thing isnt visible.

Comment: Thank you . We know that solution but as you want to figure out the problem thats why i have tried .